# Replace Table by functional programming

Tags: functional-style

Just for learning purposes I try to create a list that looks like this: {{{3, 9}, {4, 16}}, {{5, 25}, {6, 36}}}

One way to do it is by using Table:

```
Table[{j + 2 i, (j + 2 i)^2}, {i, 0, 1}, {j, 3, 4}]
```

Now I try it using functional programming, but I failed. This is what I tried:

```
Nest[Map[{#, #^2} &], Range[3, 4], 2]
```

Is it possible to create the desired result only using Nest, Map and Range? If not, what other function should I use, without using Table, but using a Pure Function instead?

Comment: oops ...  `({#, Power[#, 2]} & @ Range[3, 6] // Transpose // 
   ArrayReshape[#, {2, 2, 2}] &) == ({#, # #} & @ Range[3, 6] // 
    Transpose // ArrayReshape[#, {2, 2, 2}] &) == want`

Comment: @tomd Thanks! Then this would be even shorter: {#, # #} & /@ Range[3, 6] // ArrayReshape[#, {2, 2, 2}] &

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Partition[{#, # #} & /@ Range[3, 6], 2]
```

> {{{3, 9}, {4, 16}}, {{5, 25}, {6, 36}}}

Comment: That's not the same list! ;-)

Comment: Sorry, see update

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have used Partition

Answer (score 5):

```
Array[{#, #^2} & @@ {#2 + 2 #} &, {2, 2}, {0, 3}] (* or *)
Outer[{#, #^2} & @@ {#2 + 2 #} &, {0, 1}, Range[3, 4]]
```

> {{{3, 9}, {4, 16}}, {{5, 25}, {6, 36}}}

Removing hard-coded parameters:

```
f1 = Module[{x = #[[1]], l = Length@#}, 
    Array[{#, #^2} & @@ {#2 + l #} &, {l, l}, {0, x}]] &;
f1 @ Range[3, 4]
```

> {{{3, 9}, {4, 16}},
>      {{5, 25}, {6, 36}}}

```
f1 @ Range[4, 6]
```

> {{{4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}},
>      {{7, 49}, {8, 64}, {9, 81}},
>      {{10, 100}, {11, 121}, {12, 144}}}

And, similarly for `Outer`:

```
f2 = Module[{l = Length@#, x = #}, 
      Outer[{#, #^2} & @@ {#2 + l #} &, Range[l] - 1, x]] &;

f2 @ Range[3, 4]
```

> {{{3, 9}, {4, 16}},
>      {{5, 25}, {6, 36}}}

```
f2 @ Range[4, 6]
```

> {{{4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}},
>      {{7, 49}, {8, 64}, {9, 81}},
>      {{10, 100}, {11, 121}, {12, 144}}}

Also

```
☺ = # /. ♯_ :> ({#, #^2} & @@@ ({♯ + #} & /@ {0, (♯♯ = 0; ♯♯++ & /@ #; ♯♯)})) &;

☺ @ {3, 4}
```

> {{{3, 9}, {4, 16}}, {{5, 25}, {6, 36}}}

```
☺ @ Range[3, 7]
```

> {{{3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}, {7, 49}},
>       {{8, 64}, {9, 81}, {10, 100}, {11, 121}, {12, 144}}}

Comment: Unfortunately there are too many brackets. OP wants ` {{{3, 9}, {4, 16}}, {{5, 25}, {6, 36}}}`

Comment: @eldo, fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

```
BlockMap[{{#1[[1]], #[[1]]^2}, {#1[[2]], #[[2]]^2}} &, Range[3, 6], 2]
(* {{{3, 9}, {4, 16}}, {{5, 25}, {6, 36}}} *)
```